# Show all objects present in localStorage on a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I am storing my data from a form in localstorage in the following format:

```
Object {title: "dsadasds", dueDate: "dsadasdsa", summary: "dsadadas", body: "dasdasdas"}
Object {title: "dasdadsa", dueDate: "dasdasdadasda", summary: "dsadasdasd", body: "dasdasdas"}
```

This data is stored in localstorage every time a user submits the form. Now in a different page 'localhost:3000/notes' i wanna show all these objects stored in localStorage. Currently with the following code, its just showing the last object submitted.

```
        var form = $('#form'),
        formTitle = $('#title'),
        formDueDate = $('#dueDate'),
        formSummary = $('#summary'),
        formBody = $('#body');

        var title = formTitle.val();
        var dueDate = formDueDate.val();
        var summary = formSummary.val();
        var body = formBody.val();
        var newContent2 = $('#new-content2')

        var test = {};
        test = {
            title: title,
            dueDate: dueDate,
            summary: summary,
            body: body
        }

        localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(test));
        var LocalStoredData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'));
        console.log(LocalStoredData);

       //for retrieving data from locastorage
       var retrievedData =  localStorage.getItem('test');
       var text = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
       var showTitle = text["title"];
       var showDueDate=  text["dueDate"];
       var showSummary = text["summary"];
       var showBody = text["body"];

       $('#showTitle').html(showTitle);
       $('#showDueDate').html(showDueDate);
       $('#showSummary').html(showSummary);
       $('#showBody').html(showBody);
```

I need to loop trough all the objects (or any other mechanism)  to extract all the objects from localStorage and display them in appropriate div on the web page. I tried putting the retrieval code in the loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++)
```

but using this loop its not showing anything. How can I show all the objects present in my localStorage.

Comment: LocalStorage is a key-value store. Under which key(s) do you save your objects? Did you consider using just one key and saving an entire array of objects in it?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    try {
        item = JSON.parse(item);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(key+" is not in JSON format");
    }
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily get all the contents of LocalStorage using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, localStorage.getItem(key))
})
```

Comment: That will also get you the `.length` key